# Understand this javascript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Promise'

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am getting a javascript error in the console, which I would really like to understand. I have removed all extraneous code, leaving just an 11 line webpage. The page does work as expected, but with an error. The error given on the Chrome console is

```
VM1286:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Promise'
```

This is the file test.html, I am opening the file in Chrome locally. (file://Users/Timeto/test.html) this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var asyncFunc;
  asyncFunc = async() => {
    console.log("called the async func");
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    window.setTimeout(asyncFunc(),1000);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the console log message after 1 second of page load, **which it does do correctly.**

So why and where from comes this error? And if appropriate how to eliminate?

Comment: BTW, `window.setTimeout(asyncFunc(),1000);`  should be `window.setTimeout(asyncFunc,1000);`

Comment: thank you - when i changed this like you said, the error disappeared.
can you explain why that is?

Comment: you call the function and assign what it returns to the event listener....

Comment: @zeb3142 when you invoke `asyncFunc()` it returns a `Promise` object, while the `setTimeout` function accepts `string` values for callback names (long story, ancient history), so when you pass a `Promise` into `setTimeout` it converts it to a string and then that breaks it.

Comment: ofc, it is obvious now.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are using `var` which is not recommended, second thing you pass the function in the setTimeout function but instead you are running it, it should be like

`window.setTimeout(async () => asyncFunc(),1000);`